# Symfony constraint to prevent duplicates in overlapping time frame

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I enforce uniqueness of a value within overlapping date range in Symfony using Doctrine ORM.

I have the following entity

```php
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table("tax_component")
 */

class TaxComponent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_component_id", type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_component_name", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private string $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_component_rate", type="integer")
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(0)
     */
    private int $rate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_component_applicable_from", type="datetime_immutable")
     */
    private DateTimeInterface $applicableFrom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_component_applicable_to", type="datetime_immutable")
     */

    public function __construct(string $name, int $rate, ?DateTimeImmutable $applicableFrom = null, ?DateTimeImmutable $applicableTo = null)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

I want to make `$name` unique withing overlapping time frames of `$applicableFrom` and `$applicableTo`. For example,

```php
$repository->save(
    new TaxComponent('inter-state', 1800, new DateTime('2018-04-01:00:00:00'), new DateTime('2019-03-31T23:59:59'))
);

// The following should be allowed since there is no overlap between the two time ranges using the name 'inter-state'
$repository->save(
    new TaxComponent('inter-state', 1200, new DateTime('2019-04-01:00:00:00'), new DateTime('2020-03-31T23:59:59'))
);

// The following should fail since 'inter-state' is ambiguous during the period 2019-09-01:00:00:00 to 2020-03-31T23:59:59
$repository->save(
    new TaxComponent('inter-state', 1800, new DateTime('2019-09-01:00:00:00'), new DateTime('2020-09-31T23:59:59'))
);
```

Is there a constraint to enforce this is Symfony?

I am currency planning to check for existing entities from within `TaxComponentRepository::save`, before calling `$this->entityManager->persist`. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleaner way would be to create your own custom assert.

Starting by creating your constraint :

```
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class TaxComponentConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Another tax component overlap this one: {{ taxComponent}}';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'App\Validator\Constraints\TaxComponentValidator';
    }
}
```

And now you have to create a validator that will check if there exist an overlap with two tax component.

```
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class TaxComponentValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($taxComponentObject, Constraint $constraint)
    {
    //Check however you want if the tax component can be created (So no overlap between two existing TaxComponent)
    if($overlappingTaxComponent){
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                        ->setParameter('{{ taxComponent }}', $overlappingTaxComponent->__toString())
                        ->addViolation();
    }

    }
}
```

Here, **$overlappingTaxComponent** is a TaxComponent preventing us from making one because of your constraint.

If the constraint is properly done, you can now use it easily in your entity so that it check automatically when submitting the form :

```
<?php

//...
use App\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table("tax_component")
 * @CustomAssert\TaxComponentConstraint
 */
class TaxComponent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_component_id", type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_component_name", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private string $name;
```

Comment: This should be a class constraint and not a property constraint so it can access the other class members that need to be considered in the validation.

Comment: Otherwise you could show how to access the validator `context` to retrieve other properties, but I personally think it's 'nicer' at a class level.

Comment: Yes it would be better at class level since we are looking into three attribute to prevent the entity creation